# Select query with distinct from three tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables

**color**

```
date,id ,highlightedcolor
```

**shapes**

```
date,id,highlightedshapes
```

**height**

```
date,id, highlightedheight
```

All these tables has different number of rows but shares unique id

I need a query to select distinct date and corresponding id from all the three tables where hightlightedcolor is yellow and highlightedshapes is square and highlightedheight is short

any help is much appreciated

tried

```
   SELECT DATE,ID ,HIGHLIGHTEDCOLOR FROM COLORS WHERE HIGHLIGHTEDCOLOR ='YELLOW' UNION SELECT DATE,ID ,HIGHLIGHTEDSHAPE FROM SHAPE WHERE HIGHLIGHTEDSHAPE ='SQUARE' UNION SELECT DATE,ID ,HIGHLIGHTEDHEIGHT FROM HEIGHT WHERE HIGHLIGHTEDHEIGHT ='SHORT'
```

**error**

> Error: ER_WRONG_NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS_IN_SELECT: The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns

Comment: the column you select in the 3 tables have the same data types???

Comment: but post the real code  ..  you sample is not valid

Comment: yes they have same data types

Comment: then show the real SQL code you are using

Comment: update your question  .. for code  ..

Comment: the code seems correct  .. you have this code in a script with other  code ?

Comment: It is still not clear what you want to achieve. Maybe you want to illustrate this with data sample and expected results. So far you are selecting distinct yellow records plus distinct square records plus distinct short records. The query you are showing is syntactically correct. So it must be another query throwing that error. If the same query had a missing comma for instance that would be a typical reason for such error, e.g. `SELECT DATE ID` instead of `SELECT DATE, ID` is short for `SELECT DATE AS ID`, i.e. `ID` became a mere alias for `DATE` and you'd select two columns instead of three.

Comment: Format your code properly.  Don't just put it in one long line!!!

Answer (score 0):

using `join` and `distinct`

```
Select distinct t1.date,
                t1.id,
                t1.hightlightedcolor,
                t2.highlightedshapes,
                t3.highlightedheight
from color t1 
INNER JOIN shapes t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
INNER JOIN height t3 ON t1.Id = t3.Id
WHERE t1.hightlightedcolor = 'yellow'
AND t2.highlightedshapes ='square'
AND t3.highlightedheight ='short'
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be the shortest solution:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.date, c.id
FROM   color c
       shapes s
       height h
WHERE  c.id = s.id
AND    s.id = h.id
AND    c.hightlightedcolor = 'yellow'
AND    s.highlightedshapes ='square'
AND    h.highlightedheight ='short'
```

Comment: column date in field list is ambiguous.its not working